# How to open an URL in a browser with an authentication header?

Tags: go, url, browser, command

In Golang we can launch a browser window to open an URL using `exec.Command` method. An example can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/hyg/9c4afcd91fe24316cbf0)

My question is how can we open that URL with a header?

Comment: Simple answer: no.

Comment: no workarounds?

Comment: See https://dwheeler.com/essays/open-files-urls.html which was the first result I got searching Google for `browse to a URL by command line`.

Comment: @tharinduwijewardane I didn't downvote, there's no for rage capslock. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, you could use [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) to attach to a running Chrome instance and issue a command to navigate to a URL with specific headers.

First, Launch Chrome with Chrome Devtools Protocol enabled by using the flag `--remote-debugging-port=9222`

You'll get a response similar to `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/2393d6e8-a85d-40a2-a79e-13f1585ff336`

Pass that `ws://...` URL into the program below:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "log"

    "github.com/chromedp/cdproto/network"
    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    var devToolWsURL string
    flag.StringVar(&devToolWsURL, "devtools-ws-url", "", "DevTools Websocket URL")
    flag.Parse()

    // Create contexts.
    actxt, cancelActxt := chromedp.NewRemoteAllocator(context.Background(), devToolWsURL)
    defer cancelActxt()

    // Create new tab.
    ctxt, _ := chromedp.NewContext(actxt)

    // Custom header.
    headers := map[string]interface{}{
        "X-Header": "my request header",
    }

    task := chromedp.Tasks{
        network.Enable(),
        network.SetExtraHTTPHeaders(network.Headers(headers)),
        chromedp.Navigate("http://google.com"),
    }

    // Run task.
    err := chromedp.Run(ctxt, task)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- 9222 is the default port for this protocol but you can use any port
  you want.
- I didn't include the `exec.Command` code for brevity.

**References:**

- [Header example](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/headers/main.go)
- [Remote Chrome control example](https://github.com/chromedp/examples/blob/master/remote/main.go)

**UPDATE**

[Found a simpler way](https://github.com/chromedp/chromedp/issues/422#issuecomment-511176490). You can just launch Chrome straight from `chromedp` by overriding the default *headless* option:

```
func main() {
    // Create contexts.
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:], chromedp.Flag("headless", false))
    actx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(actx)

    // Call cancel() to close Chrome on some condition.
    if false {
        cancel()
    }

    // Custom header.
    headers := map[string]interface{}{
        "X-Header": "my request header",
    }

    task := chromedp.Tasks{
        network.Enable(),
        network.SetExtraHTTPHeaders(network.Headers(headers)),
        chromedp.Navigate("http://tested.com"),
    }

    // Run task.
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx, task)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am sure someone will benefit from it. But my requirement is to open the url in a CLI application which runs on an user's machine. I cannot be sure he has installed chrome on it.

Comment: @17xande Can you please explain "just launch chrome from chromedp"? I need to open a chrome browser with a given auth-header via Powershell and dont know what to do with the above function. A file "chromedp" seems not exist in windows.